# Send Message in Telegram Messenger Bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

One simple question: 
is there any way to send a message to a user that never start chat with bot? For example can we send a message with username instead of chat id ??

simple pseudo code:

```
sendMessage(@username, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bots can't initiate a dialogue proactively at this time, even user clicked inline button.

You can make a suggestion to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport), or ask your user `/START` your bot.

Comment: Thanks for reply :)